# Project Euler #7: 10001st prime

Tags: c#, programming-challenge

This is my implementation of [Project Euler #7](https://projecteuler.net/problem=7).  Have I overdone it again?  Is there anything else I should or should not do?  It runs in 9 milliseconds on my computer.

> What is the 10001st prime number?

```
static int NPrimeGenerator(int nPrime)
{
    List<int> primes = new List<int>();

    primes.Add(2);
    int nPrimeVal = 3;

    while (primes.Count != nPrime)
    {
        int sqrtNPrimeVal = (int) Math.Sqrt(nPrimeVal);

        foreach (int i in primes)
        {
            if (nPrimeVal % i == 0) { break; }

            if (i >= sqrtNPrimeVal)
            {
                primes.Add(nPrimeVal);
                break;
            }
        }

        nPrimeVal += 2;
    }

    return primes[primes.Count - 1];
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
    s.Start();

    int nPrime = NPrimeGenerator(10001);

    s.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine(nPrime);

    Console.WriteLine(s.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Have I overdone it again?

I think it's not bad at all. I don't think you overdid anything.

> Is there anything else I should or should not do?

Notice that the condition `primes.Count != nPrime` of the `while` loop is unnecessary evaluated many times:
when nothing was added to the list,
the re-evaluation is pointless.

You could improve this by changing it to an infinite loop with `while (true)`,
and moving the original condition to the point right after adding a prime to the list. If the target count is reached, break out of both loops.

```
TOP: while (true)
{
    int sqrtNPrimeVal = (int) Math.Sqrt(nPrimeVal);

    foreach (int i in primes)
    {
        if (nPrimeVal % i == 0) { break; }

        if (i >= sqrtNPrimeVal)
        {
            primes.Add(nPrimeVal);
            if (primes.Count == nPrime)
            {
                break TOP;
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    nPrimeVal += 2;
}
```

But I think a bigger problem with this code is the poor naming,
especially of variables:

- `nPrimeVal` implies a prime value, possibly the n-th prime. But that's not the case, making it very misleading. `possiblePrime` would be better.
- `nPrime` implies.... I don't really know what. It's the target count, so I'd name it `targetCount`
- `NPrimeGenerator` is not a great name. The method returns the n-th prime number, so `GetNthPrime` would seem more natural

It's good that you skip even numbers when searching for the next time.
What would be even better is to use a *sieve*,
a popular choice being the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Lastly,
a little thing, 
but note that in the condition `i >= sqrtNPrimeVal` you can drop the equality (making it `i > sqrtNPrimeVal`),
as in the case of equality the condition will not be reached,
thanks to the `break` right before it.

Answer (score 3):

Considering the implementation:

- Everything that has been mentioned by janos.
- Since you are skipping even numbers, checking nPrimeval%2 is redundant.

Optimisation:

- Since primes can be represented as `6x+1` or `6x-1`, you could run the roop as afast as three times the current execution by following a simple algorithm.

  1. Add `2,3` into primes initially.
  2. Start with `nPrimeVal` as `5` a representation of `(6x-1)`.
  3. Run the loop as currently done.
  4. Inside the loop check for `nPrimeVal` (`6x-1`) and `nPrimeVal+2`(`6x+1`) and after the loop increase nPrimeVal by 4.
  5. Rest follows the current algorithm.
     Link: [Project Euler Problem #10](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/75765/project-euler-problem-10/76943#76943)

Everything is clean and good. Above optimisation is just for information sake :) Do include jason's inputs.