# Project Euler 35: Circular primes below 1 million

Tags: python, performance, programming-challenge, primes

I'm doing another Project Euler problem, [number 35](https://projecteuler.net/problem=35):

> The number, 197, is called a circular prime because all rotations of
>   the digits: 197, 971, and 719, are themselves prime.
>
> There are thirteen such primes below 100: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 31,
>   37, 71, 73, 79, and 97.
>
> How many circular primes are there below one million?

```
import math  
num = 0  
primeList = []

def isprime(test):
    if test == 2:  
        primeList.append(2)  
        return True  
    elif test < 2:  
        return False  
    else:  
        for i in primeList:  
            if i > math.sqrt(test):
                break
            elif test % i == 0:
                return False
        primeList.append(test)
        return True

def rotations(n):
    answer = []
    rotation = n
    while not rotation in answer:
        answer.append(rotation)
        rotation = int(str(rotation)[1:] + str(rotation)[0])
    return answer

for i in range(2,1000000):
    numList = rotations(i)
    valid = True
    for j in numList:
        if not isprime(j):
            valid = False
    if valid:
        num += 1

    print(num)
```

I need help improving my code speed.  What I really think is happening is the `rotations()` function is slowing the whole thing down.

Answer (score 2):

Trial division repeatedly can get very expensive, and is not scalable in terms of computation time. Especially when you are running your rotation check during the process.

I would suggest getting a list together, then filtering that out. That way it is more efficient, and also when you rotate a number you just check if it is in the list, rather than rechecking it for primality slowly. Lookup tables are usually a good recommendation for these things, as the rotated elements overlap in spots. (such as 79 & 97, having to check if they are prime twice. It gets worse for longer numbers!)

To get all primes below 1,000,000 you can implement the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to quickly get the list of primes.

```
from math import sqrt

def sieve(n):
    primes = [True] * (n+1)
    primes[0] = primes[1] = False

    for x in range(4,n+1,2):
        primes[x] = False

    for x in range(3,int(sqrt(n))+1,2):
        if(primes[x]):
            for y in range(x*x,n+1,x):
                primes[y] = False

    return primes
```

Now you just go through the returned list, and for each `True` entry, you can check if it's rotatable.

And here is a simpler way to right a rotation. This one shifts left.

```
def rotate(n):
    n=str(n)
    return n[1:]+n[:1]
```

And with that rotation, and the sieve available to us, we now just rotate the number, and check if it is `True` in the sieve! Return false if any rotation of `n` is `False`, else return `True` if we can't find any non-primes.

```
def isRotatable(n, primes):
    for x in range(2,n):
        n = rotate(n)
        if not primes[int(n)]:
            return False
    return True
```

Now for a main method to just go through and print the results for us! I'm using `main` because I'm not sure what else to name it.

```
def main(n):
    primes = sieve(n)
    for x in range(2, len(primes)):
        if(isRotatable(x,primes)):
            print(x)
```

Altogether these pieces should work rather quickly. The longest part I found was it actually outputting to the interpreter, possibly writing to a file may be quicker.

Answer (score 2):

Other people have pointed out algorithm optimisations. I reckon you'll get even faster results if you have a look at [my answer to a pretty similar question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/58610/efficiency-of-project-euler-problem-35).

Let's go for actual code review:

**A bug in `rotations`**

> ```
> def rotations(n):
>     answer = []
>     rotation = n
>     while not rotation in answer:
>         answer.append(rotation)
>         rotation = int(str(rotation)[1:] + str(rotation)[0])
>     return answer
> ```

One can see that you have written something that looks like a smart enough solution that stops when similar rotations are found.

Writing a few tests, it looks like it works properly :

```
print(rotations(123))
print(rotations(1233))
print(rotations(1212))
```

However, there is a bug hidden in the fact that you lose some information converting from int to string back and forth.

Consider the following examples :

```
print(rotations(10))
print(rotations(100))
print(rotations(1000))
```

Removing the conversions, you'd get :

```
def rotations(n):
    answer = []
    rotation = str(n)
    while not rotation in answer:
        answer.append(rotation)
        rotation = rotation[1:] + rotation[0]
    return answer
```

Not that it does not really change anything for the final result because impacted numbers contain a `0` and at least one rotation is not prime.

**Code organisation**

Try to put your code actually doing things behind an [`if __name__ == '__main__':` guard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578308/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-main-method-in-python).

Your function `isprime` does a lot more than its name suggests.

Try to write small simple methods doing one things so that you can easily test them.

Answer (score 1):

Optimisation:

- Since primes can be represented as `6x+1` or `6x-1`, you could run the loop by following a simple algorithm <[LINK](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/75765/project-euler-problem-10/76943#76943)>.

  1. Add 2,3 as circular primes initially.
  2. Start with `i`as 5 a representation of (6x-1).
  3. Run the loop as currently done.
  4. Inside the loop check for `i`(6x-1) and `i+2`(6x+1) and after the loop increase `i`by 4.
  5. Rest follows the current algorithm.

     for i in range(2,1000000): // With above alogrithm it would be 3 times faster.
- `numlist` is calculated every time for `197`, `971`, `719`. Instead if your `isPrimes` instead represented 3 values : IS_PRIME, IS_NOT_PRIME, IS_CIRCULAR_PRIME. So you would not have to rotate once you have already checked it before.
  As JPMC suggested, its best to have the primes calculated first
- Move this out of the loop and store it in a temp variable.

  ```
  if i > math.sqrt(test):
  ```